# How can I test the click of a button within an <a> without activating the link

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

If I have the following:

```
<a [href]="some-url" target="_blank">
  <button (click)="onClick()">Press me</button>
</a>
```

```
function onClick(){
  this.service.doSomething();
}
```

Using Jasmine/Karma, how can I test that `doSomething` was called, without opening any link or other unwanted browser behavior? I have tried:

Setting `href` to empty string and `target` to `_self`, which continually refreshes the browser window:

```
const anchor = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('a'))?.nativeElement as HTMLAnchorElement;
anchor.href = '';
anchor.target = '_self';
```

Setting `href` to `#` and `target` to `_self`, which opens an embedded Karma instance within the browser:

```
const anchor = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('a'))?.nativeElement as HTMLAnchorElement;
anchor.href = '#';
anchor.target = '_self';
```

Returning `false` from the click handler function, which tests successfully but breaks the app:

```
function onClick(){
  this.service.doSomething();
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer led me to removing the `a href` and using a click handler to call `window.open` instead.

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Press me</button>
```

```
function onClick(){
  window.open(some-url, '_blank');
  this.service.doSomething();
}
```

```
spyOn(window, 'open'); // prevent new tab being opened
const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'))?.nativeElement as HTMLButtonElement;
button.click();
```

This also has the advantage that you can `spyOn(window, 'open')` to check that the call was made.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be entirely what you want but I would just get a handle on the button and click that and know that the click will go to the button if the `a` was clicked because that's how HTML/JavaScript works I assume.

```
spyOn(window, 'open');
const button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement as HTMLButtonElement;
button.click();
// continue
```

Comment: Actually this is what I started with, and the button click still activates the anchor hyperlink.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try spying on `window.open` so it does nothing. I am hoping `href` uses `window.open`.

Comment: good idea but doesn't work, window is still opened and spy not called.

Comment: thanks for your input, gave you an upvote as it led me to the answer